# How to hide/show particular sections on another page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page (pageA) with 7 projects. all projects have a **More Details** button. I have another page (pageB) with those 7 project's details in seperate sections. When the **More Details** Button is clicked on pageA I want it to navigate to pageB and show a particular section, and the other section's should be hidden. Can please someone guide me?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your particular sections in something like accordions.
My approach would be :

- Hide `more-details-section` parts by default (pageB)
- Add IDs to your projects (pageB)
- Specify in your `more-details` links the id (pageA, like pageB#project1)
- Get the ID from the url to toggle the concerned `more-details-section` accordion (pageB)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can pass a prop as the project Id of which project details have been clicked.
In next step on page B apply conditional operator in which to show the section which satisfy the requirement props.project_Id==project_Id.

{props.project_Id==project_Id && <div></div>}
{props.project_Id==project_Id && <div></div>}
{props.project_Id==project_Id && <div></div>}
{props.project_Id==project_Id && <div></div>}
{props.project_Id==project_Id && <div></div>}
{props.project_Id==project_Id && <div></div>}
{props.project_Id==project_Id && <div></div>}
```

Comment: The question didn't mention any usage of frameworks. Thus, the answer should cover how to do that using vanilla HTML/CSS/JS.